# Image texture refuses to line up with the UVs

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

Even though my UVs are lining up with what I'm doing in the texture paint editor, the result does not visibly line up with what the UV map and image texture suggest it should look like. I have tried smart UV unwrapping, modifying some of my seams, and all of that jazz, and nothing seems to be working. I am completely confused as to why this is happening, and I really need some help in sorting it out.

Below can be found a pair of screen shots from my screen showing what I'm seeing. On the top left, you can see my character's UV map overlayed on the image used in the texture node found at the bottom. On the top right, you can see the results.

[image: Here is the UV map and the resulting character]

[image: Here is the rendered character and the shader editor]

In case its relevant, my OS is Ubuntu and I my system is an HP ENVY 750-400 Series PC.

Answer (score 1):

AH! I had two objects overlaping each other. The one on top aparently had a different UV map than the one I was painting on.